# How to apply form validation without <form> tag in Angular2

Tags: angular

I was wondering if there is a way to validate a form in **Angular 2** without using the `form` tag? For example below I want to make it a required field

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use form tag?

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a way, I think for me it's better. I can find that it can be done in angularjs 1 but I cannot see any in angular 2 @rook

Comment: Angular detects `form` tag and adds functionality around it. This tag shouldn't affect any of your layout.

Comment: If you want field level validation, form is best option.

Answer (score 28):

Form controls can be standalone (without a parent form), whether using declarative form controls or reactive form controls.

For declarative (using `ngModel`) you can just do something like

```
<input #model="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="value" type="text" required/>
<div *ngIf="model.invalid" style="color: red">Required</div>
```

For reactive forms you can do something like

```
<input [formControl]="control" [(ngModel)]="value" type="text"/>
<div *ngIf="control.invalid" style="color: red">Required</div>

// in component
this.control = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
```

See [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9vQMHKztGM7teDyMJ77T?p=preview)

For more information on using Angular forms in general, see [the docs/tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

Comment: Had to change version of zone.js to 0.8.12. See this fork: https://plnkr.co/edit/o1TwYdWzb3NgXZrDWGz0?p=preview

Answer (score 13):

Apart from using form controls directly as @peeskillet has shown in his answer, you can attach the form *directive* to any tag using its `ngForm` selector:

```
<div ngForm #newRuleForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!newRuleForm.valid" (click)="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that you can't use standard form functionality like `<button type=submit>` in this case, but I find this approach very valuable when I want to use template-driven forms while retaining a simple way to validate a group of fields together.

Comment: Hey man, this is what I'm looking for. But how do you add validations this way? I tried using FormBuilder, but it didn't work.

Comment: @eestein since these are plain template based forms, attaching validations works the same as with any template based form: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#simple-template-driven-forms

Comment: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" error when adding ngform to div

Comment: Button is not disabled: not working -  <div class="visitor-entry" ngForm #newRuleForm="ngForm">
          <!-- [ngClass]="{'validate':vName.errors && (vName.dirty || vName.touched)}"-->
         <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
  </div>
       
          <div class="add-btn-cont">
            <button  [disabled]="!newRuleForm.valid" class="icon-btn" id="addVisitor" title="Add" (click)="addVisitor();">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
          </div>

        </div>